# Could someone explain me why my input text doesn't become yellow?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a simple HTML form and when I try to style my `.yellow` it doesn't work. 
My HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="">
    <label for="tekstass">Tekstass</label><br>
    <textarea name="tekstas" cols="10" rows="10"></textarea><br>

    <div id="container">
    Name:<input type="text"  name="textas" placeholder="enter your name" ><br>

    Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password here"><br>

    Name:<input type="text"  name="textas" placeholder="enter your name" ><br>

    <div class="mid">Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password here"><br>

    Name:<input type="text"  name="textas" placeholder="enter your name" ><br>

    Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password here"><br>
    </div>

    Name:<input type="text"  name="textas" placeholder="enter your name" ><br>
    <div id="middle">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password here"><br>

    Name:<input type="text"  name="textas" placeholder="enter your name" ><br>

    Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password here"><br>

    <div class="yellow">Name:<input type="text"  name="textas" placeholder="enter your name" ><br>

    Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password here"><br>

    Name:<input type="text"  name="textas" placeholder="enter your name" ><br>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div id="ending">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password here"><br>

    Name:<input type="text"  name="textas" placeholder="enter your name"><br>

    Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password here"><br>

    Name:<input type="text"  name="textas" placeholder="enter your name" max="5"><br>

    Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password here"><br>
    </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS looks like this :

```css
.yellow input[type=text] {background-color:yellow;}

#container input {background-color:pink;}

.mid input[type="password"] {background-color:aqua;}
```

I might be dumb but if someone could explain why my `.yellow input[type=text]` isn't working I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @csmckelvey .yellow input[type=text] will find the inputs that are under an element that has the yellow class, which is currently the case.

Comment: Then it is being overwritten by `#container input {background-color:pink;}`

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The direct solution is to add !important .yellow input[type=text] {background-color:yellow !important;}

Answer (score 1):

Your styling for yellow `input[type=text] {background-color:yellow;}` is spot on, so no problems there. The problem is that you're using an ID to style your container, which is overwriting your class style.

Your container ID has a higher rank than your yellow class, as IDs at the same level as a class will take priority. Try using `.container` instead of `#container` and that'll fix the issue.

IDs should only really be used when manipulating parts of your HTML with JavaScript. Try to avoid styling them where possible to avoid issues like this in the future. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Quotes for input type "text" are missing. Please add them.
Code:

```
yellow input[type="text"] {background-color:yellow;}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually fix the problem.

Comment: #container .yellow input[type="text"] {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

Comment: You should test that to see if it works and then if it does change your answer.